# raise ValueError when enum class field is changed

Tags: python, django, django-models, enums

**Enum Class**

```
class QuestionValidationTag(Enum):
    FREE_TEXT = "Free text"
```

**model**

```
validation_tag = models.CharField(choices=[(tag.value, tag) for tag in QuestionValidationTag],
                                      null=True, max_length=200)
```

I have change the enum `FREE_TEXT`

```
class QuestionValidationTag(Enum):
        FREE_TEXT = "make free text"
```

after that I have tried to run my application and raise `Value Error`. As well as I also try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` (though it's not needed as my understanding). But this also gives me the error.

> raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.**name**))
>
> ValueError: 'Free text' is not a valid QuestionValidationTag

**is there any suggestion how I resolve this issue with changing the enum value?**

**Full Trace of Makemigrations**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_
from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_arg
v
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 7
8, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 201, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 110, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Robiul_Alam_Backup\habijabi_\habijabi_src\habijabi_labo\habijabi_server\apps\chatbot\migrations\0001_ini
tial.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "D:\Robiul_Alam_Backup\habijabi_\habijabi_src\habijabi_labo\habijabi_server\apps\chatbot\migrations\0001_ini
tial.py", line 150, in Migration
    ('validation_tag', models.CharField(choices=[('Free text', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Free text')
), ('Hobby', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Hobby')), ('Affirmative', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionV
alidationTag('Affirmative')), ('Gender', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Gender')), ('Age', apps.chatbot.c
ommon.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Age')), ('Drink category', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Drink catego
ry')), ('Chu-hi brand', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Chu-hi brand')), ('First impression', apps.chatbot
.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('First impression')), ('Taste', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Taste'
)), ('Greetings', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Greetings')), ('Drinking Scene', apps.chatbot.common.enu
ms.QuestionValidationTag('Drinking Scene')), ('Drinking Frequency', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Drinki
ng Frequency')), ('Recent Activities', apps.chatbot.common.enums.QuestionValidationTag('Recent Activities'))], max_length=2
00, null=True)),
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\enum.py", line 291, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\enum.py", line 533, in __new__
    return cls._missing_(value)
  File "D:\ROBIUL~1\HABIJABI_~1\AI_DJA~1\AI_DJA~1\lib\enum.py", line 546, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 'Free text' is not a valid QuestionValidationTag
```

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace for makemigrations failure?

Comment: @mfrackowiak I have updated my question with full trace. Thank you.

Comment: show us 0001_initial.py migration

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs, because you've removed or changed some value in `Enum` field (so old value is no longer valid with that enum), but one of the historical migration still uses that value inside `Enum` and that just won't work. You have to trace that migration (according to stacktrace, it is `0001_initial`) and fix it so this value in enum is no longer used.

Comment: yes I have changed the enum field value and already mentioned in my question. But want to change without error.

Comment: change 0001_initial to use `QuestionValidationTag.FREE_TEXT` instead of `QuestionValidationTag('free text')`. This is how you should use enums anyway, by key not by value. Or better, just change the migration to specify a list of string tuples instead of using the class object, so you can change the keys and values of the Enum without issues. The thing is, choices is not important in migrations anyway, because it's not enforced at the database level.